# SpringBoot: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file [] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to return an image from a springboot controller as the Resource object but I'm getting the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: file [/home/user/eclipse-workspace/MedVibes-1/ironman.png] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length`

Controller

```
@RestController
    public class MedVibesController {
        @Autowired
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
        @RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource("ironman.png");
    return resource;
    }
```

I've an ironman.png file in both the MedVibes-1 directory as well as it's `static` folder
[image]

Still I'm getting the FileNOtFoundException? What's wrong with my code?How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileSystemResource` looks for the file in the FileSystem. if you want to use this, you have to specify full path.

You can use `ClassPathResource`

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("static/ironman.png");
```

By default, it will look into resources folder.

Another way

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:ironman.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

add the path:

```
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource("/static/ironman.png");
```

or

```
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource("/ironman.png");
```

depends on wich of the both files you want